# Auto Import facebook comments into Drupal website

Tags: 7, social-network

Using Drupal 7. When i share a node on Facebook, i wish to automatically import Facebook comments made on Facebook for that node into the node's page on Drupal. I've tried a couple of modules including [Facebook comments Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/facebook_comments)

[1](https://www.drupal.org/project/facebook_comments): https://www.drupal.org/project/facebook_comments_block and [Facebook comments social plugin](https://www.drupal.org/project/facebook_comments)

but they only help users to comment on your site using their facebook accounts, no way to import comments made by users on the content page when it is shared to facebook.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch comments on a post using graph API. But you must know the Facebook post id of the corresponding node.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<postedid>/comments
```

Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043527/how-to-get-all-comments-and-likes-for-a-facebook-post